# Implicitly deleted special functions with std::chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, noexcept

I have some code like this

```
#include <chrono>
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::time_point;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() noexcept = default;
    MyClass(MyClass const&) noexcept = default;
    MyClass(MyClass&&) noexcept = default;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const&) noexcept = default;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) noexcept = default;
private:
    time_point<steady_clock> timestamp; 
};

int main() {
    MyClass myObject;
    MyClass myOtherObject(myObject);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile it results in

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:18:10: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr MyClass::MyClass()’
  MyClass myObject;
          ^~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:8:5: note: ‘constexpr MyClass::MyClass() noexcept’ is implicitly deleted because
its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ‘’
     MyClass() noexcept = default;
```

But compiles fine if I remove the `noexcept` specifier for the default constructor:

```
MyClass() = default;
MyClass(MyClass const&) noexcept = default;
MyClass(MyClass&&) noexcept = default;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass const&) noexcept = default;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) noexcept = default;
```

So I have 2 questions:

- **How come time_point's default constructor isn't `noexcept`?** I mean, as far as I understand it only contains an integer of some type representing the time since epoch, which is supposed to be 0 for the default constructor if I believe [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point)
- **Why does removing `noexcept` from only the default constructor work?** If the compiler says that it had generated `MyClass()` and not `MyClass() noexcept` and therefore deleted it, it should be the same for `MyClass(MyClass const&)`, right? But the compiler lets me do the copy without complaining here...

Comment: `time_point` is a template, and it cannot know in advance whether the constructors of the actual duration type are `noexcept`.

Comment: @j6t First, `vector` is a template too and some of its constructors are `noexcept` regardless of the type. Second, it can know in advance: if you look at `vector`'s default constructor, it's only `noexcept` if the `Allocator` type's default constructor is, through `noexcept(noexcept(Allocator()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - How come time_point's default constructor isn't noexcept?

When `noexcept` first went into the standard in C++11 the committee was very hesitant to "over apply" it.  `noexcept` is much easier to add to the standard than to remove.  In applying it conservatively, "conditional" `noexcept` was often shunned.

I would like to see "conditional" `noexcept` applied to `<chrono>`.  For the `time_point` default constructor the `noexcept` would be conditional on if `rep` is `noexcept` default constructible.  `rep` doesn't have to be an integer.  It might be a class type with a throwing default constructor.  But the specialization `steady_clock::time_point` would always be `noexcept` because it's `rep` *is* required to be integral.

> - Why does removing noexcept from only the default constructor work?

Because [`time_point` has a user-declared default constructor but a compiler-supplied copy constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.point.general).  This is one example of how compiler-supplied special members can be so much "smarter" than user-declared ones.

The compiler-supplied copy constructor of `time_point` effectively already has a "conditional" `noexcept`.  You get this for free by writing less code.  Had the `time_point` default constructor been compiler-supplied (which it *should* have been), then it would work in your example too.